# Adding additional button on on-screen buttons

Tags: java, android

Currently the design of the app that I am working on has no space for the menu button on the action bar. Some android devices does not have menu hardware button and then I saw an app where in there is an additional button on the on-screen buttons, I want to implement this on the app.

I want to know how to add this button on the on-screen buttons:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4yjk.png]

Answer (score 0):

This button replaces the hardware menu button on devices which don't have a physical menu button. But it is only used when apps still need to use the old menu button. I would strongly recommend to clean up your action bar and to implement the new design convention because the old menu button is deprecated.

You should read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html) to become familiar with the topic.

Comment: Seems like there is no other way than to re-design the action bar, also here's an article regarding the menu button: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html

Comment: You are right. As the article points out correctly it is legacy. Maybe you should ask on stackOverflow how your design could be improved?

Answer (score 0):

You should get this with new project created. Add in `res` folder named `menu` and in this folder add `main.xml` copy paste

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.asd.MainActivity" > <!--Change this to your Activity--!>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never"/>

</menu>
```

Then in your activity add this

```
@Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

[image]